# tqdm progress bar for chained iterables

Tags: python, python-itertools, tqdm

If I want to combine two iterators in Python, one approach is to use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain).

For example, if I have two ranges `range(50, 100, 10)` and `range(95, 101)`, I can get a range `[50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]` with `itertools.chain(range(50, 100, 10), range(95, 101))`.

`tqdm` is an extensible progress bar in Python.  However, by default it doesn't seem to be able to count the number of items in a `itertools.chain` expression, even when they are fixed.

One solution is to convert the range to a list.  However this approach doesn't scale.

Is there a way to ensure `tqdm` understands chained iterators?

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import itertools
import time

# shows progress bar
for i in tqdm(range(50, 100, 10)):
    time.sleep(1)
   
# does not know number of items, does not show full progress bar
for i in tqdm(itertools.chain(range(50, 100, 10), range(95, 101))):
    time.sleep(1)
    
# works, but doesn't scale
my_range = [*itertools.chain(range(50, 100, 10), range(95, 101))]    
for i in tqdm(my_range):
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a workaround than an answer, because it just looks like `tqdm` can't handle it right now. But you can just find the length of the two things you chained together and then include the argument `total=` when you call `tqdm`.

```py
from tqdm import tqdm
from itertools import chain

# I started with a list of iterables
iterables = [iterable1, iterable2, ...]

# Get the length of each iterable and then sum them all
total_len = sum([len(i) for i in iterables])

# Then chain them together
main_iterable = chain(*iterables)

# And finally, run it through tqdm
# Make sure to use the `total=` argument
for thing in tqdm(main_iterable, total=total_len):
    # Do stuff
```

Answer (score 4):

As of 2023 there is a shorter way by using *itertools* straightly from *tqdm* library:

```
import numpy as np    
from tqdm.contrib.itertools import product

a, b = np.arange(1,10,1), np.arange(20,30,1)

for a1, b1 in product(a,b):
    print(a1, b1)
```